# Can I specify application path in @RequestMapping on controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Can I use EL to specify my application context path on my Spring Controller using something like `@RequestMapping("${pageContext.request.contextPath}")`? Actually, I get an 404 error. So my question is how to map controller on context root?

I presume `@RequestMapping("/")` cannot do the job when app is not alone on the server, and url looks like:
`http://localhost:8080/myapp/mypage`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${pageContext.request.contextPath}")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {

    }
}
```

PS: I've already added the app path prefix into every single url on my JSPs, like `<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/search" method="post">`. Now I need to make the same trick for my Spring Controllers to make it work when... wheather app deployed as ROOT app or as "just another app on this server".

Comment: You want to add your context path as a prefix for every single URL?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The mappings are already relative to the context root. Spring's `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/`. The Servlet container will already have resolved that your app's Servlet should be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

you can add in the application.properties config file the root context path. That root context path will be the prefix path to all the controller paths.

application.properties

> server.contextPath=/myapp/mypage

controller

> @RequestMapping("/test")

Result:

> http://localhost:8080/myapp/mypage/test